# Error during mfpdev app webupdate

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

while I was uploading webupdate with command

```
mfpdev app webupdate
```

I obtain the follow error

```
Error: Web resources could not be deployed for platform: ios
Error: The mfpdev app webupdate command failed: INVALIDPLATFORMVERSION
```

Android Platform doesn't send me errors.

Please help me.

EDIT: Enviroment Versions

```
Cordova CLI: 6.3.1 
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-rc.3
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.1
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.7
Ionic App Scripts Version: 0.0.36
ios-deploy version: 1.8.6 
ios-sim version: 5.0.8 
OS: macOS Sierra
Node Version: v4.4.3
Xcode version: Xcode 7.3.1 Build version 7D1014
```

EDIT2: Plugins list:

```
com.testfairy.cordova-plugin 2.0.9 "TestFairy Plugin"
cordova-plugin-compat 1.1.0 "Compat"
cordova-plugin-console 1.0.4 "Console"
cordova-plugin-contacts 2.2.0 "Contacts"
cordova-plugin-device 1.1.3 "Device"
cordova-plugin-device-motion 1.2.3 "Device Motion"
cordova-plugin-dialogs 1.3.1 "Notification"
cordova-plugin-geolocation 2.4.0 "Geolocation"
cordova-plugin-globalization 1.0.5 "Globalization"
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 1.6.1 "InAppBrowser"
cordova-plugin-mfp 8.0.2016101414 "IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation"
cordova-plugin-mfp-jsonstore 8.0.2016101414 "IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation JSONStore"
cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy 2.2.0 "Request Location Accuracy"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 4.0.0 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.2.0 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.0 "Whitelist"
cordova-sms-plugin 0.1.11 "Cordova SMS Plugin"
ionic-plugin-keyboard 2.2.1 "Keyboard"
nl.x-services.plugins.insomnia 4.1.0 "Insomnia (prevent screen sleep)"
```

and platform.json:
`"ios": "4.2.1"`

Comment: What is the cordova-ios version you're using in your Cordova project?

Comment: Thanks for the details, but that's not what I asked. Please use the command  "cordova plugins list".

Comment: Now run "cordova platforms list"

Comment: Try updating your cordova-ios to the latest.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to successfully test Direct Update with cordova-ios@4.3.1.

When using the `mfpdev app webupdate` command, the changed web resources were packaged and deployed to the MobileFirst Server. Later on, once the application attempted to obtain a token from the MobileFirst Server, a Direct Update dialog appeared onscreen and was successfully applied.

Thoughts:

- Update your MobileFirst CLI: `npm install -g mfpdev-cli`
- Update the iOS platform in your Ionic application

Comment: Hi Idan,


C:\wl_workspace\mfpProject>mfpdev app webupdate

Verifying server configuration...

Deploying to server:'http://172.16.60.61:9080' runtime:'mfp'

Error: Web resources could not be deployed for platform: android

Error: The mfpdev app webupdate command failed: ERRORDURINGEXTERNALSCRIPT

mfpdev -v
8.0.0-2018040312


cordova android -v
8.0.0
C:\wl_workspace\mfpProject>cordova platform
Installed platforms:
  android 6.1.2

android@6.1.2